# closedness of subtracted sets

Tags: convex-analysis, closed-map

While working on convexity I stumbled upon a Theorem that started with:

Let $V_1, V_2 \subseteq \Bbb R^n$ be convex sets such that $V_1 \cap V_2 = \emptyset$ and $V_1-V_2$ is closed.

Note that in this case $V_1-V_2 := \{x \in \Bbb R^n:x=p-q, p\in V_1, q\in V_2\}$

Now I'm curious, does the notion that $V_1-V_2$ is closed imply that both $V_1$ and $V_2$ are closed? If not, what would be a counter example? Or if so, how could i proof that?

I managed to prove the theorem without solving this question, but I couldn't figure it out and now I can't seem to let it go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Okay. Unfornately it is wrong. Here is the counter example:**

Consider: $A = (-2, -1]$ and $B = [0,\infty)$. Then, $A,B$ are both convex, disjoint, $A$ not closed and $B - A = [1, \infty)$ is closed.

Thx to @gerw for tipping of.

Comment: This is not true. You know that the limit $b - a$ lies in $C$, hence it can be written as $\hat b - \hat a$ with $\hat a \in A$ and $\hat B \in B$. You may not get $\hat a = a$ and $\hat b = b$.

Comment: @gerw: ah, I got sloppy. Thx. I will think about it again.

Comment: As stated, it is not true. Take $A = \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $B$ be your favorite non-closed set. It might be possible to prove it using the convexity *and* empty intersection.

Comment: @gerw: now the counter example is correct.

Comment: This counterexample is neat :)

Comment: After accepting your proof this counter example blew my mind! Thank you!